# 'p-calendar' is not a known element error even after importing CalendarModule

Tags: angular, primeng

I am getting below error  when using p-calendar in angular2 even after importing CalendarModule.

import { CalendarModule } from "../../../vendor/primeng/components/calendar/calendar";

```
    Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'p-calendar' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-calendar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-calendar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <div>
        Calendar
        [ERROR ->]<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="todaysDate"></p-calendar>
    </div>
```

[image: Calendar error]

Comment: where did you import the CalendarModule?

Comment: Which module did you add it to? Can you edit your question and add the code for the module where you're importing it please?

Comment: importing module as below import { CalendarModule } from "../../../vendor/primeng/components/calendar/calendar";

Comment: Did you add it into the `imports` array inside the module?

Comment: show you app.module.ts file and routing file

Comment: importd module as   <code> import { CalendarModule, Calendar } from "../../../vendor/primeng/components/calendar/calendar"; </code> but still facing issue

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you had missed to import `CalendarModule` inside your application. You have to import the `CalendarModule` inside your `AppModule` from `primeng` library and inject it inside your `imports` of `AppModule`.

```
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
   BrowserModule, 
   FormsModule,
   CalendarModule, //<-- injected module here.
   FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I have imported CalendarModule but still faces same issue

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: exporting primeng calendar component was commented earlier.Uncommenting that resolved issue.